# setInterval with Audio Files Not Working on iOS mobile

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop two file using javascript. Here's the sequence:

1. User clicks a button
2. A countdown timer starts and File 1 plays (onclick)
3. Then File 2 plays after X ms (setTimeout)
4. File 1 plays again (setInterval)
5. File 2 plays again
   ... etc until the timer ends.

It works fine on desktop. But I can't get the sounds to loop on mobile. In other words, it gets stuck at step 3.

Here's the URL: https://benpages.com/nova/

And here's how the how I've set up the audio:

```
function audioTrack() {
    const soundOne = new Audio('./files/low-bell.mp3');
    const soundTwo = new Audio('./files/high-bell.mp3');

    inhale = document.getElementById('inhale').value * 1000;
    exhale = document.getElementById('exhale').value * 1000;
    breathCycle = inhale + exhale;

    soundOne.play();
    soundOffset = setTimeout(() => {soundTwo.play()}, inhale);
}
function loopTrack() {
    audioTrack();
    audioLoop = setInterval(audioTrack, breathCycle);
}
```

loopTrack is triggered onclick along with other functions.

```
const startTimer = function () {

    time = startingMinutes * 60;

    if(activeSession == true){
        clearInterval(countdown);
        clearInterval(audioLoop);
        clearTimeout(soundOffset);
    }

    if(startingMinutes != "") {
        activeSession = true;
        updateCountdown();
        loopTrack();
        countdown = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
    } else {
        alert('Enter a time and try again');
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Just tried on an IPhone and I noted that: if Inhale is grether than Exhale it works on mobile also. Otherwise it works only the first time. On desktop it works always. Maybe this could help you to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. I've got the same behavior here. Also using an iPhone.